# Как сериализовать тело get запроса?

Tags: javascript, angular

Есть объект c сильной вложенностью, который мне нужно отправить телом в http get запросе. Однако, если я использую `toString(), JSON.stringify(data)` или отправляю просто {params: data}, где data - объект HttpParams, то или не отправляется вложенные объекты, или перед ? ставится слэш.

```
const data: any = {
  one: 'one',
  two: 'two',
  three: {
    four: 'four',
    five: 'five',
    six: {
      seven: 'seven'
    }
  }
};
```

Тут будет site.com/test/?и корректный объект

```
this.http.get('site.com/test?' + JSON.stringify(data));
```

Тут будет тело, но вложенные объекты со значением mysite.com/test?one=one&two=two&three=%5Bobject%20Object%5D

```
this.http.get('site.com/test', {params: data})
```

Comment: [Using object as as a parameter of get method of Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52802793/2881286) - советуют убрать `{}`: `this.http.get('site.com/test', params: data)`

Answer (score 1):

Это не совсем вопрос по Angular.

```
const data: any = {
  one: 'one',
  two: 'two',
  three: {
    four: 'four',
    five: 'five',
    six: {
      seven: 'seven'
    }
  }
};

function createParams(obj) {
    const params = [];
    for (let key in obj) {
        const typeS = Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[key]);
        let value = obj[key];
        if (typeS === '[object Object]') {
            value = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(value));
        }
        params.push(`${key}=${value}`);
    }
    return params.join('&');
}

// Ну и если это Angular, то можно и так
this.http.get(`site.com/test?${createParams(data)}`)
```

Ангуляровский `HttpParams` с этой задачей с дефолтным `HttpUrlEncodingCodec` не справится. Он проверяет только на массив. Остальное считается примитивом. [Чекните](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/params.ts) метод `toString` из исходников.

`HttpParams` принимает в качестве опции поле `encoder`, куда можно передать кастомный кодек для парсинга объектов любой вложенности. Собственно, мою функцию выше можно реализовать в рамках этого кодека и получить нужный вам результат.

Comment: вопрос по angular, потому что в нем есть встроенные инструменты для этого

Comment: под конкретно эту задачу - нет. Есть два варианта, как можно ее сделать. Первый я указал. Второй - это создать свой HttpParamsCodec и засетать его в `options.encoder`. По по сути это задача не `Angular`, а обработка конкретного юзер сценария, который может возникнуть в любой среде и фреймворке

Comment: Посмотри связанный вопрос, вроде как он должен сам это разруливать.

Comment: это как раз и есть тот вопрос, что задал @bruce. вложенные объекты неправильно парсятся HttpParams. Поэтому в том кейсе говорят, чтобы убрали лишнюю обертку. А здесь как раз и надо передавать вложенный объект.

Comment: Похоже что так. Хотя вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58855948/angular-http-client-how-to-pass-nested-params-object-to-get-api) автор говорит что у него работало :)

Comment: Судя по исходникам, из не примитивов `HttpParams` обрабатывает только массивы. Остальное считает примитивами и передает как есть. В случае объекта просто вызовется `toString()`

Comment: Логично, добавь ссылку на исходники с этим местом в ответ, чтобы видно было почему не работает

Comment: Ага, обновил ответ